# Threading queue, is the code right?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I wrote a little multi-host online-scanner. So my question is the code correct? I mean, the program does what it should but if I look in the terminal at the top command, it shows me from time to time a lot of zombie threads.

The code for scan and threader function:

```
def scan(queue):
    conf.verb = 0

    while True:
        try:
            host = queue.get()
            if host is None:
                sys.exit(1)
            icmp = sr1(IP(dst=host)/ICMP(),timeout=3)
            if icmp:
                with Print_lock:
                    print("Host: {} online".format(host))
                saveTofile(RngFile, host)

        except Empty:
            print("Done")
        queue.task_done()

def threader(queue, hostlist):
    threads = []
    max_threads = 223

    for i in range(max_threads):
        thread = Thread(target=scan, args=(queue,))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for ip in hostlist:
        queue.put(ip)
    queue.join()

    for i in range(max_threads):
        queue.put(None)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

P.S. Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: When you see _zombies_ it is almost for sure that you do not join children threads correctly. Seems like you didn’t forget to join them but I am not sure about your intentions around `ip` iteration over `hostlist`. Joining queue? Also without an example of what imports do you use and what do you pass for `threader` parameters, I cannot reproduce it nor fully comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot more threads than you have cores then you aren't really getting any benefit from spawning them, and even worse python has the global interpreter lock so you don't get real multithreading unless you use multiple processes.  Use multiprocessing and set max_threads to multiprocessing.cpu_count().

Even better, you could use a pool.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    results = p.map(scan, hostlist) 
# change scan to take host directly instead of from a queue
# if you change
```

And that's it, no messing with queues and filling it with None to make sure you kill all your processes.

I should add, make sure you create your process pool inside the main module!  Your code in its entirety should look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def scan(host):
    # whatever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        results = p.map(scan, hostlist)
```

Comment: thanks guys, your comments helped to unterstand whats going wrong!